# The argument type 'GestureDetector Function can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Widget Function

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider, dart-null-safety

**The argument type 'GestureDetector Function(BuildContext, WalkthroughProvider, Widget)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Widget Function(BuildContext, dynamic, Widget?)**

```
class WalkthroughStepper extends StatelessWidget {
  final PageController controller;
  WalkthroughStepper({required this.controller}) : assert(controller != null);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      children: List.generate(
        3,
        (int index) {
          return Consumer(
            builder: (BuildContext context, WalkthroughProvider walkthrough,
                Widget child) {
              return GestureDetector(
                onTap: () {
                  controller.animateToPage(index,
                      duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
                      curve: Curves.ease);
                },
                child: Container(
                  color: Theme.of(context).scaffoldBackgroundColor,
                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 25.0),
                  child: Container(
                    height: 5.0,
                    width: 40.0,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: index <= walkthrough.currentPageValue
                          ? Theme.of(context).primaryColor
                          : Colors.grey[300],
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
                    ),
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 5.0),
                  ),
                ),
              );
            },
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make callback widget nullable `Widget child` to `Widget? child`

```dart
Consumer(
  builder: (BuildContext context, WalkthroughProvider walkthrough,
      Widget? child) {
```

Comment: Glad to help, you can explore more about [null-safety](https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety) and [someone-answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)